# How to add footer view after set adapter in in pre-4.4

Tags: android, listview, android-adapter, android-adapterview

I have attached footer after setAdapter, now it works good from KitKat but it does not work before KitKat versions.

The solution I got is from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24719557/4291272) SO question is:

1. addFooterView(footer);
2. setAdapter(adapter);
3. removeFooterView(footer);

but I wanted to attach footer view after setAdapter.

Answer (score 0):

Why not displaying a view over the listview.

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <SomeView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/recyclerView" />

</RelativeLayout>
```